# Подскажите, как можно упростить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, инспекция-кода, dict

Написал код к задаче, где нужно написать функцию, которая будет искать совпадения с заданным словарем, флаг функции `letter_case` отвечает за то, нужно ли сравнивать регистр символов или `Python` и `python` это одно и то же слово.

Но мне вообще не нравится, что для поднятого флага я продублировал такой же кусок кода, уверен что можно добавить логику, чтобы это вместить компактно, но я не могу до неё додуматься...

И хотел бы по возможности услышать замечания о коде: как я мог его упростить или выбрать легче решение, соответствует ли мой код общепринятым правилам названия переменных и `PEP-8`!

```
articles_dict = [
    {
        "title": "Endless ocean waters.",
        "author": "Jhon Stark",
        "year": 2019,
    },
    {
        "title": "Oceans of other planets are full of silver",
        "author": "Artur Clark",
        "year": 2020,
    },
    {
        "title": "An ocean that cannot be crossed.",
        "author": "Silver Name",
        "year": 2021,
    },
    {
        "title": "The ocean that you love.",
        "author": "Golden Gun",
        "year": 2021,
    },
]

def find_articles(text_filter, letter_case=False):
    new_d = []
    if letter_case:
        for d in articles_dict:
            for key_d, val in d.items():
                if str(val).find(text_filter) != -1:
                    new_d.append(d)
        return new_d
    else:
        text_filter = text_filter.lower()
        for d in articles_dict:
            for key_d, val in d.items():
                if str(val).lower().find(text_filter) != -1:
                    new_d.append(d)
        return new_d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**С точки зрения кода:**

1. Если у вас функция находит совпадения со словарем, то логично в нее этот словарь передавать.
2. Переменная `articles_dict` - в названии фигурирует словарь, а на деле это - список словарей, может ввести в заблуждение.
3. В цикле итерируетесь по `d.items()`, но при этом ключ не используете.
   Тогда уже логичнее итерироваться по `d.values()`.
4. Так как вам не важен конкретный индекс совпадения строки, то лучше вместо функции `find` использовать оператор `in`.
5. Ваши вложенные циклы с условием прямо намекают на использование `list comprehenshions`, такая запись будет более компактной и "питонячей".
6. `return` можно вынести в конец функции, поскольку у вас два взаимоисключающих условия, которые никогда не выполнятся одновременно.

Почитать подробнее про `list comprehenshions` можно [**здесь**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

**С точки зрения задачи:**

Можно решить, используя следующий алгоритм:

1. Преобразовываем список словарей в один список, содержащий все слова для поиска.
2. В случае, если хотим произвести поиск без учета регистра, то все элементы списка преобразовываем в нижний регистр, то же самое с поисковой строкой.
3. Пробегаемся по списку и находим требуемое совпадение.

Код:

```
def find_articles(text_filter, articles, letter_case=False):
    list_words = [x for y in [list(x.values()) for x in articles] for x in y]
    if not letter_case:
        text_filter = text_filter.lower()
        list_words = [str(x).lower() for x in list_words]
    return any(text_filter in str(word) for word in list_words)


articles = [
    {
        "title": "Endless ocean waters.",
        "author": "Jhon Stark",
        "year": 2019,
    },
    {
        "title": "Oceans of other planets are full of silver",
        "author": "Artur Clark",
        "year": 2020,
    },
    {
        "title": "An ocean that cannot be crossed.",
        "author": "Silver Name",
        "year": 2021,
    },
    {
        "title": "The ocean that you love.",
        "author": "Golden Gun",
        "year": 2021,
    },
]

print(find_articles('End', articles, True)) # True
print(find_articles('END', articles, True)) # False
print(find_articles('END', articles, False)) # True
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста объяснить вторую строку? Для меня сложная конструкция еще...

Comment: @Pain это называется `list comprehenshion`, сейчас я в ответе добавлю ссылку на документацию, сможете почитать. По сути - это просто замена вашим вложенным циклам, создает новый список на основании элементов из другой структуры данных и эти элементы можно и фильтровать по условию и сразу же преобразовывать. Я использовал этот прием для того, чтобы из списка словарей сделать один список, содержащий все слова из словарей

Comment: Спасибо большое, а вы еще в 4 пункте написали что я использую функцию index, но я делал через find - она тоже работает с индексами?

Comment: @Pain опечатка :) да, функция `find` находит индекс первого совпадения. Вот [документация](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp)